# Intermittent Socket Close Warning Resulted in Internal Error

Tags: sockets, proxy, warnings, internal

I am getting intermittent socket warning in weblogic server and because of that internal error in web server.

The warning message is **BEA-000449** which says socket has been closed as no data read from the socket within the specified timeout of 5 sec.I am able to change the time and i can see that it is taking effect.

In the error log I can see the following error:

`Internal Error: proxy error reading status line`

In the access log I see **502 response codes**.

I am using:

- Weblogic server versions 10.3.5 and 10.3.6 (with both versions the problem persists)
- Apache Http Server 2.2.22
- Using mod_proxy

I have applied `SetENV` parameters in web server as I came to know that there is some bug in apache mod_proxy.I tested various scenarios for keep Alive on/Off changing different parameters etc, but nothing has worked for me.

Its been more than 9 weeks i've been working on this error but unable to resolve it.
I would really appreciate if someone can help me with this issue.

Comment: Is there a proxy in front of the web server? Describe your topology please. And are there actual application failures associated with these errors?

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been resolved.

There was some OS related problem in our environment because of which request was taking time...
We applied patches as suggested by oracle.With that to be on the safer side we have increased the connection timeout of weblogic server to 25 Seconds.